# Scrollbar lost after using ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

[![My ScreenShoot][1]][2]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V16o0.png before
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu6GB.png after

this is my javascript, that refreshing my tabel data with calling an AJAX :

```
function AvailableSeatMenu(kode) {
    $.get("function_and_ajax/ajax.php", {
        ajx: "ReadCashierMenu"
    }, function (data, status) {
        $("#dtable").html(data);
        $("#cssTable").DataTable({
            "pageLength": 5,
            responsive: true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            select: {
                style: 'single',
                info: false
            }
        });
        $(".lbl_Loading").hide();
    });
}
```

the AJAX echo-ing the table and its data. it was too long to paste it here..

This problem happens when the table on my modal is refreshed using ajax, i dont know why this happen.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, please put some more effort into your question: edit your question to include relevant parts of your code, describe the problem more precisely. Read [ask]

Comment: sorry, i've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an answer in the stack page you mentioned: @Paul Tomblin. I don't know whether or not it is the answer of that question, but I guess (95%) that it's the answer of your question.

Suppose your content is in a class named ajax_content; you should run this code when the ajax request completes:

```
$('.ajax_content').each(function(){
    $(this).resize();
});
```

This code assures that all divs, spans, etc. with the ajax_content class will be resized. Remember that the ajax_content class should have the scroll: auto; attribute.

If you want to resize the whole page, you can use the answer I mentioned on that page:

```
$(window).resize();
```